# Renaming the default content source from "Local SharePoint sites"

Tags: 2013, search, managed-property, refiner, content-source

I need to rename the default content source in Search to something other than "Local SharePoint sites". I've noticed however that the name of it cannot be edited. The only other way I can think to do this would be to delete it and create a new one in its place, but that's not preferable because I don't know what complications might arise from it. Does anyone know if that's safe to do, or if there's another way to go about it?

Ultimately the goal is to change the name in the refiners, as we're using the ContentSource managed property as a refiner in this environment, and just want a more explicit name for this particular source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, but you can create new Content Sources and remove the start addresses from the original.

Comment: Yup, turns out you can't even delete the original! But removing the start addresses from it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is read only property and I couldn't update it with PowerShell too. I can't imagine any adverse affects of creating a new content source and removing the default one.